# How do you log stdout and stderr for the MDA in procmail?

Tags: procmail

I'm relatively new to using fetchmail and procmail.  I inherited a system from somebody and I am trying to debug the MDA that we wrote to deliver messages.  This is a program written in perl and has "print" statements in it.  I was wondering how to have procmail write the output (stdout) from the MDA to a log file someplace.  It doesn't seem to go to the output specified in the LOGFILE variable.  Only procmail's output goes there.

Answer (score 0):

Standard error goes to `LOGFILE`.  Standard output can be redirected just as in a shell script.  You're not showing any code, so this is speculative, but something like

```
:0c
* conditions, perhaps
| /path/to/script.pl --verbose --quiet --paradoxical --oxymoronic >log
```

If you want the output in Procmail's log file, simply add `2>&1` at the end (or fix the Perl script, as it seems that what it is printing should be going to standard error, based on your brief description; or add standard system logging facilities).